# Two different return values mongoose.deleteOne?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good morning.

I'm working on a back-end project, and I use NodeJS with mongoose.

I found two different return values for deleteOne() on the web :

- {n, ok, deletedCount}
- {acknowledged, deletedCount}

Here are the sources :
https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/mongoose-deleteone-922
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#examples

In my project, I had a return value equal to {acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 1} and I could not find a way to reproduce the {n, ok, deletedCount}.

What is the difference between the two patterns ?

Thanks in advance !

Elias.

Answer (score 1):

I would think this has something to do with the version of the `MongoDB`. The first example is a forum post from `3 years` ago and the second example is the newest docs.